# How do i add int items to comboBox in jumps of 10 ?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
            {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Reduced by: " + i.ToString());
            }
```

This will add 90 items to the comboBox1.
I want to add 9 items 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90

How can i add it in jumps of 10 ?

Comment: You know what an if statement is, right? You probably heard of modulo too? You know it's possible to mix these ideas up, correct? (Or just do +10, yeah, haha) You're asking very very basic questions lately, why don't you try things by yourself, read a basic tutorial or look for existing answers on SO.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: While you *could* do it with modulo, that's not the simplest way to do it, IMO...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, it's pretty late, my brain is a little on slow :( +10 is indeed much better. But still, two extremely basic questions on the same code is slightly annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 10; i <= 90; i+=10)
        {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Reduced by: " + i.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

give a try like this:

```
for (int i = 10; i <= 90; i=i+10)
            {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Reduced by: " + i.ToString());
            }
```

or:

```
for (int i = 10; i < 100; i=i+10)
                {
                comboBox1.Items.Add("Reduced by: " + i.ToString());
                }
```

Comment: Both won't work. You have no assignment in your for-loop. It's always i+10, but i get's never set to that value. It does not even compile that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clear but long version. Note that this uses an extra helper variable and loops 90 times as in your original approach, which is not as efficient as the answer from mr100:

```
int cnt = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 90; i++)
{
    cnt++;
    if (cnt == 10)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Reduced by: " + i.ToString());
        cnt = 0; //Reset  
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?? It works and is clear. I know the code can be made shorter, but that does not mean it is not OK!

Comment: It's simply not performant. You got 9 times more loop transits than if you just use the power of for-loop, incrementing i by 10. Moreover you got a if for each loop. Of course this is not much of performane waste in a normal case. But for high-performance applications this is a really bad approach.

Comment: as ots clear that jump of 10 is required then why iterating 90 times instead of 9 times

Comment: OK, you are right, I edited my post. I was just happy to finally being able to answer a question in here :) My code still works :-)

Comment: No one blames you for that, but you should try to assemble good solutions. Sure it works, but it's more like a hacked way to do so. And as Ehsan said, you could easily decrease the amount of loop transits by looping 9 times and multiplying i by 10 in the Add()-method ;)

Comment: Performance is unlikely to be a problem. That's not really the best reason to avoid writing code like this. The better reason is because it's unclear. It takes me a while of studying it to figure out what the heck it's doing. It looks more complicated than it is. And that's a bad thing. Following the standard idioms is not only clearer to future programmers who have to maintain your code, it's also good practice. The idioms became standard for a reason.